# How do I query for item with non-empty array with mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following code that works as expected:

```
Mongoid::Criteria.new(Question).where(:related_question_ids.size => 0)
```

However, I would like to perform the query to return questions with related_questions array greater than 0.  For example,

```
Mongoid::Criteria.new(Question).where(:related_question_ids.size.gte => 0)
```

Is there a way to do this with mongoid or mongodb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [$size operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24size) to query by array sizes. Consider the following example using the JS shell:

```
> db.foo.drop()
> db.foo.insert({_id: 1, x:[1,2]});
> db.foo.insert({_id: 2, x:[]});
> db.foo.insert({_id: 3, x:3});

> db.foo.find({x: {$size: 0}})
{ "_id" : 2, "x" : [ ] }

> db.foo.find({x: {$size: 1}})

> db.foo.find({x: {$size: 2}})
{ "_id" : 1, "x" : [ 1, 2 ] }

> db.foo.find({x: {$not: {$size: 2}}})
{ "_id" : 2, "x" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "x" : 3 }

> db.foo.find({x: {$not: {$size: 0}}})
{ "_id" : 1, "x" : [ 1, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "x" : 3 }
```

I'm not familiar with Mongoid, but I found an example using `$size` in [this documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html).

Two caveats with `$size` are that it cannot utilize an index (other parts of the query certainly can) and it cannot be used in range queries. If you don't mind the additional bookkeeping, a viable option is to store the array's size in a separate field (likely indexed) and query on that any way you like.

Comment: This definitely works, and the correct way in mongoid would be:
Question.where(:related_question_ids.not => {"$size"=>0}).size

Comment: Kamilski81 has the actual answer to this question about Mongoid.

Answer (score 4):

This query search if exists any object in the related_question_ids[0] field

Using js shell

`db.questions.find("related_question_ids.0": {exists => true} )`

Using mongoid

`Mongoid::Criteria.new(Question).where(:"related_question_ids.0".exists => true)`

You can search greater any size

`Mongoid::Criteria.new(Question).where(:"related_question_ids.3".exists =>true)`

This solve your problem

Comment: `:some_relation_ids.exists => true`  would match the empty array `[]`. 
I found the `:some_relation_ids.nin => [nil, []]` solution to work best to retrieve "present" (non-empty) items. It is very ugly, but a prettier solution would be a $empty/$present operator added to Mongoid, or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to use the `.nin` (Not IN) form of the query:

```
Mongoid::Criteria.new(Question).where(:related_question_ids.nin => [nil,[]])
```

This will only return a Question where the related_question_ids is no nil and not an empty array.

Conversely, you can define `:related_question_ids` to have a default value (`:default => []`) and then you only need to query for `.ne` (Not Equal), like so:

```
Mongoid::Criteria.new(Question).where(:related_question_ids.ne => [])
```

Either should work.

Comment: I found this solution to be better, and it's written in Mongoid not just mongo syntax.